# shading area outside of kml boundary

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone seen a way to shade/color areas of a google map that are outside of a boundary/shape created by a KML file?

An example usage would be that only the area inside the boundary/shape would be interactive (click listeners etc.), and the shaded area outside of the boundary would ignore all actions aside from the basic map functionality, like moving the map back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option I have been working on (doesn't quite completely work, but the concept may address your question):

1. Create a KML file of the area of interest (in the example US states)
2. Invert it by adding an outer boundary of the whole world
3. Either display it on your map using an additional KmlLayer or import it into FusionTable (like the example)
4. Be sure to suppress infoWindows on the "inverted" layer

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_State_invert_noClick.html) 
  - Doesn't work for Virginia or Alaska 
  - Hawaii is problematic.
  - Limits the minimum zoom to 5.