# Whole world KML with innerboundaries displays wierd in google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a kml file that looks like the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>KML file with polygon for bird species range</name>
    <description>Source various books and websites</description>
    <Style id="rangecolour">
      <LineStyle><color>660000FF</color><width>1</width></LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle><color>660000FF</color></PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="linecolour">
      <LineStyle><color>660000FF</color><width>3</width></LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark><name>distribution/range</name>
      <description></description>
      <styleUrl>#rangecolour</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
              -180.0,180.0,0.0 
              -180.0,-180.0,0.0 
              180.0,-180.0,0.0 
              180.0,180.0,0.0 
              -180.0,180.0,0.0 
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
        <innerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
              153.056374,-27.500658,0.0 
              153.056374,-27.524105,0.0 
              153.093109,-27.524105,0.0 
              153.093109,-27.500658,0.0 
              153.056374,-27.500658,0.0 
            </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </innerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

My intention is to do a "hole" inside the entire world to get shadded all the world outside a boundaries (this is just an example), but, for some reason that I don't know, in Google Earth works fine, but in google maps (API v3, at least... is the one I'm using with "google.maps.KmlLayer(url.kml)"...) not.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer boundary is:

```
        <coordinates>
          -180.0,180.0,0.0 
          -180.0,-180.0,0.0 
          180.0,-180.0,0.0 
          180.0,180.0,0.0 
          -180.0,180.0,0.0
        </coordinates>
```

which is a very narrow square (between -180 and +180)

The KML displayed below uses this for the polygon (the whole world with a small hole):

```
<Placemark><name>distribution/range</name>
  <description></description>
  <styleUrl>#rangecolour</styleUrl>
  <Polygon>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          180,85 
          90,85 
          0,85 
          -90,85 
          -180,85 
          -180,0 
          -180,-85 
          -90,-85 
          0,-85 
          90,-85 
          180,-85 
          180,0 
          180,85 
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
    <innerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          153.056374,-27.500658,0.0 
          153.093109,-27.500658,0.0 
          153.093109,-27.524105,0.0 
          153.056374,-27.524105,0.0 
          153.056374,-27.500658,0.0 
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </innerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

[This](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=66.202659&lng=-94.839844&zoom=3&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/so_wholeworldkmld.kml) works for me with [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), doesn't work with [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

[Another example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=37.155939&lng=-79.497071&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/virginia_inverted_kml.xml)

I don't know why, the [Google Maps KML parser](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fso_wholeworldkmlb.kml&hl=en&ll=-27.515427,153.073711&spn=0.084648,0.110378&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.641638,0.883026&t=h&z=13) and [KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_wholeworldKMLb.kml) have pretty much always been broken this way.

[Related question: shading area outside of kml boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317143/shading-area-outside-of-kml-boundary)

Comment: My intention is to do the whole world and even in google earth appears shadded all the world, but aparently using a kmlLayer in google maps API, as you said, it became a very narrow square, but the intencion is to "go" in the another direction... :( 
Anyway, now I'm traying to use geoxml3 to see if this library improve it or not. I'll let you know the results. 
Thank you!!

Comment: OK, beautiful, with geoxml3 I can, and with this kml file you posted I can "cover" the rest of the world. Very useful! Thank you so much! Now I need to zoom / focus the non-shadded zone... How did you do in your sample in "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=-27.521011&lng=153.075531&zoom=12&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/so_wholeworldkmlb.kml"? Thank you!!

Comment: The parameters in the URL lat=-27.521011&lng=153.075531&zoom=12

Comment: Ok, in this case I guess I need get a point in my "inner boundaries" and use it to zoom to it. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on what the "hole" looks like, you can compute the bounds of that "polygon" and center the map on that bounds (with Map.fitBounds).  For the square hole in your example, that is trivial (a square/rectangle that is lined up north/south, east/west defines a bounds).