# How to get the latitude and longitude of the entire map border on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to make a polygon with hole. In this case, there will be two coordinates outerCoords and innerCoords, where outerCoords will be the entire map, and innerCoords will be a city.
If anyone can help me here, I would greatly appreciate it.

I don't know how to get the coordinates of the entire map.

Comment: `map.getBounds()` (or make the outer coordinates cover the whole world. Related [Whole world KML with innerboundaries displays wierd in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534907/whole-world-kml-with-innerboundaries-displays-wierd-in-google-maps), or [Google Map API v3 shade everything EXCEPT for polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130323/google-map-api-v3-shade-everything-except-for-polygon))